# Comparing a String Array to Array List

Tags: java

I currently have a String Array

```
String[] properSequence = ability.getSequence();
```

And I want to compare it to an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> sequence
```

As of right now I'm doing,

```
boolean matchesSequence = true;

String[] properSequence = ability.getSequence();

int index = 0;
for(String s : sequence) {
   String s1 = properSequence[index];
   if(!s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
      matchesSequence = false;
      break;
   }
   index++;
}

if(matchesSequence) {
   // Matches, code
}
```

I was wondering if there's an easier/prettier way of doing this, seems a bit redundant.

Comment: In this case, using a foreach-loop makes things less legible. Use a classic index-based loop, and then do `if(!properSequence[i].toLowerCase().equals(sequence.get(i).toLowerCase())) return false` or something along those lines. Even better, use Apache StringUtils, which will take care of null safety for ya.

Comment: Also, I would *definitely* encapsulate the list comparison into its own method - something along the lines of `private boolean compareList(Iterator a, Iterator b)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code may throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Check the bounds of array as well as the list as shown below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(sequence.size(), properSequence.length); i++) {
   if(!sequence.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(properSequence[i])) {
      matchesSequence = false;
      break;
   }
}
```

**Alternatively,**

```
for(int i = 0; i < sequence.size() && i < properSequence.length; i++) {
   if(!sequence.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(properSequence[i])) {
      matchesSequence = false;
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in equals method:

```
if(!Arrays.equals(sequence.toArray(),properSequence))
    matchesSequence = false;
```

Comment: This will violate what OP wants to achieve. OP wants to compare in a case-insensitive way.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the String[] into an ArrayList and compare those two, but you can't do that if you want equalsIgnoreCase() in the comparison. However, if you put all the elements in the String[] and the ArrayList in upper (or lower) case, you could do this:

```
if (Arrays.asList(properSequence).equals(sequence)) 
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and Lists are only considered equal to each other if the elements are equal and in the same order.

To compare an Array of object to a List of the same object you can do the following using the [Arrays#compare](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#compare(T%5B%5D,T%5B%5D,java.util.Comparator)) method.  Different versions have different capabilities. This example uses `Strings` and does a case insensitive compare.  It also makes use of `List.toArray` introduced in JDK 11

```
List<String> list = List.of("A", "B", "C");
String[] array1 = { "a", "b", "c" };
String[] array2 = { "a", "c", "b" };

for (String[] array : new String[][] { array1, array2 }) {
    
    if (Arrays.compare(array, list.toArray(String[]::new),
            String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) == 0) {
        System.out.printf("%s equals %s%n",
                Arrays.toString(array), list);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%s does not equal %s%n",
                Arrays.toString(array), list);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
[a, b, c] equals [A, B, C]
[a, c, b] does not equal [A, B, C]
```

Comment: so Arrays.compare does work with an array of arrays and internally automatically iterates over each array and compares it to the list which is cast to an array?

Comment: Almost.  But not an array of arrays.  It does iterate over the arrays and does a 1 to 1 compare.  But the List is not cast to an array but the `toArray` method returns an array of the type specified. 
That method was introduced in JDK 11.  The array of arrays I am using is just to specify separate single D arrays for demonstration.  Each of those test arrays are compared to the List.

Comment: To compare an array of arrays to another of the same,  something like a `DeepCompare` would need to exist. But the Arrays class does not provide that.